# Confused between passing strings to a function (C)

Tags: arrays, c, string, function, pointers

Why this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void slice(char *st, int m, int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    while ((i + m) < n)
    {
        st[i] = st[i + m];
        i++;
    }
    st[i-1] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char st[] = "Hello";
    slice(st, 1, 6);
    printf("The value of string is %s\n", st);
    return 0;
}
```

And this doesn't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void slice(char *st, int m, int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    while ((i + m) < n)
    {
        st[i] = st[i + m];
        i++;
    }
    st[i-1] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char*st = "Hello";
    slice(st, 1, 6);
    printf("The value of string is %s\n", st);
    return 0;
}
```

In first I initialized my string using:

- `char st[]="Hello";` (using array)

And in latter I used:

- `char*st="Hello";` (using pointer)

I'm kind of getting confused between these 2 initialization types, what's the key difference between declaring a string by using `char st[]="Hello";` and by using `char*st = "Hello";`.

Comment: Latter points to read only constant memory, former copies data to read/write memory.

Answer (score 3):

With `char st[] = "Hello";`, `st[]` is a modifiable *array* of characters.  The call `slice(st, 1, 6);` takes the array `st` and converts to a pointer to the first element of the array.  `slice()` then receives that pointer, a pointer to modifiable characters.

With `char *st = "Hello";`, `st` is a *pointer* that points to a *string literal* `"Hello"`.  With the call `slice(st, 1, 6);`, the function receives a copy of the pointer - a pointer to the string literal. Inside `slice()`, code `st[i] = ...` is attempting to modify a *string literal*, that is *undefined behavior* (UB).  It might work, it might fail, it might work today and fail tomorrow - it is not defined.

Do not attempt to modify a *string literal*.

---

> ... passing strings to a function ...

In both cases, code does not pass a *string* to `slice()`, but a *pointer* to a string.  Knowing that subtle distinction helps in understanding what is truly happening.

Answer (score 2):

This is an artifact of old syntax in C:

```
char * s = "Hello world!";
```

is a non-const character pointer to *const* memory. It is still permitted by syntax, but the string is still not a mutable object. To be pedantic it should really be written as:

```
const char * s = "Hello world!";
```

In contrast:

```
char s[] = "Hello world!";
```

allocates a local (on the stack), mutable array and *copies* the string data to it (from wherever the non-mutable copy is stored in memory). Your function can then do as it likes to your local copy of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The type char [] is different from the type char* (char*  is a variable - int. but char[] is an array which is not a variable). However, an array name can be used as a pointer to the array.
So we can say that st[] is technically similar to  *str .

**the problem in the 2nd version of your code**

If you have read-only strings then you can use  `const char* st = "hello";` or simply `char* st = "hello";` . So the string is most probably be stored in a read-only memory location and you'll not be able to modify it.
However, if you want to be able to modify it, use the malloc function:

```
char *st= (char*) malloc(n*sizeof(char)); /* n-The initial size that you need */
// ...
free(st);
```

**So to allocate memory for `st`, count the characters ("hello"-strlen(st)=5) and add 1 for this terminating null character , and functions like scanf and strcpy will add the null character;

so the code becomes :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void slice(char *st, int m, int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    while ((i + m) < n)
    {
        st[i] = st[i + m];
        i++;
    }
    st[i-1] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char *st =malloc(6*sizeof(char))  ;
    const char *cpy="hello";
    strcpy(st, cpy); /* copies the string pointed by cpy (including the null character) to the st. */
    slice(st, 1, 6);
    printf("The value of string is %s\n", st);
    return 0;
}
```

1. you can fill your string also by a for loop or by scanf() .
2. in the case of a large allocation you must end your code  with `free(st);`